# Implementing unit of work using DI and Without EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, castle-windsor, unit-of-work

I have asp.net MVC aplication with castle windsor working as DI and interceptpor.

Currently Dapper is used for ORM mappring, Dapper is a simple object to entity mapping provider which work with ADO .Net connection, common objects.

We already have repository and business service layer in place, now i want to Implemente unit of work.

I know EF has got automatic transaction capability and SaveChanges() made all entity changes persistence.

Is there any way to have Unit Of Work for non EF, multilayer application ?

Comment: What about simply using TransactionScope (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)? It's some sort of a platform-provided unit of work.

Comment: any guideline how should we implement TransactionScope. Basically I want to wrapped every my business call with this TransactionScope and ended with TransactionScope.Complete().

Comment: TransactionScope is the most simple thing to use. You just wrap *any* .NET code in a using(TransactionScope...) block, and finish by a Complete() or Rollback(). for example: http://neonlabs.structum.net/blog/easy-net-transaction-management-with-transaction-scope/

Comment: Thanks dove, actually i'm looking for some automated implementation which work something without needed to write transaction scope in the service method level. instead a mechanism which which identify when BAL call started and ended. And all method will have transaction by default.

Comment: Are you sure you want wrap all your BAL in transaction? It could have impact on performance, because all used resources will be locked during the transaction.

Comment: May be you are correct, but I'll will try to limiting it on some save, updates methods, once i have implementation in place, will take a look  to your answer provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some sort of AOP.
Look at this example http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/transaction.
You can wrap your method with transaction using the attribute or even better you can declare that it will be used on all methods from your BAL like this:

```
[assembly: TransactionScope( AttributeTargetTypes = "MyBALNamespace.*",
AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public,
AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public )]
```

as stated here : http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging

**Update**

When you are using `TransactionScope`, try to avoid unnecessary escalation of transaction to MSDTC. If you have open two connections (even to the same database) during the `TransactionScope` it will immediately escalates to DTC which have impact on performance (and sometimes it can lead to unwanted exceptions on scope dispose) - it is behavior of SQLServer2008. You should use only one connection during the scope ore close the first before opening another.